# What's in the box at the end of Lovecrafts's Reanimator?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, herbert-west-reanimator

At the end of *Herbert West: Reanimator*, West has a box delivered to him which he incinerates. The contents of the box are never explicitly mentioned but is it implied as to what's inside?

My guess is that it's

> Clapham-Lee's head

but why would he send it to West and why would West incinerate it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The box is a trick.  Knowing West will suppose it to be his head and incinerate it, Clapham-Lee knows West will head directly down to the incinerator.  This is where he needs for him to be, so that he and his team can break through the wall and destroy him.

Answer (score 4):

It is said that Clapham's voice is coming from the box, rather than the wax head on his body; presumably West incinerated the box because he hoped destroying the head would destroy the zombie.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to what Viergacht said, nowhere in the story does it say that the voice is coming from the box. However, it states, "Nor did any sound come from the box, after all." In fact, the only words spoken by any member of the horde were from another member (Express-prepaid) when dropping off the box; it is not suggested the words came from the box. Therefore, I would have to agree with Radujevach. Clapham-Lee is said to have been be a highly intelligent man that had a close working relationship with the men. So, it is entirely plausible that he would know how West would react (taking the box to the incinerator).